# How do I get sphinx to recognize decorated python functions

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators

Sphinx does not document functions wrapped with a decorator. I have tried using class style decorators and function style decorators but to no avail. These functions do not appear in my generated html whereas other functions in the same module do appear

The only hack that has semi-worked is by wrapping my class decorator with the decorator decorator but this then doesn't use the `__call__` function in the class and I need to return a value from the decorator

```
import decorator
import functools

@decorator.decorator
def MyDecoratorA(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    # do things
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

def MyDecoratorB(fn):

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        # do things
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@MyDecoratorA
def TestA(a, b=None):
    """This is a doc

    :param a: variable b
    :type a: int
    :param b: variable b
    :type b: list
    :returns: None
    """
    pass

@MyDecoratorB
def TestB(a, b=None):
    """This is a doc

    :param a: variable b
    :type a: int
    :param b: variable b
    :type b: list
    :returns: None
    """
    pass
```

I then have a batch file that runs

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -l -M -T -o /tmp/source/testfunctions ${DIR}/modules/testfunctions/ 1>/dev/null
make html
```

This generates a file called testfunctions.rst with a section for each module within the testfunctions folder

```
testfunctions.cluster module
----------------------------

.. automodule:: testfunctions.cluster
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: With a [mcve], it would probably be easier to help.

Comment: ALL functions are documented

Comment: Its just example code

Comment: You mention a class with a `__call__` method. It's not in your example code.

Comment: I tried to implement the decorator as a class to see if that would help but it didnt. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not really. I cannot reproduce your problem. The decorated functions do appear in my generated html.

Comment: added the relevant parts from my build script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138023/discussion-between-dale-and-mzjn).

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented in sphinx manual](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction):

> Note
>
> If you document decorated functions or methods, keep in mind that autodoc retrieves its docstrings by importing the module and inspecting the **doc** attribute of the given function or method. That means that if a decorator replaces the decorated function with another, it must copy the original **doc** to the new function.
>   From Python 2.5, functools.wraps() can be used to create well-behaved decorating functions.

Comment: I have tried this and the problem is that the signature of the function changes and the list of arguments are hidden behind *args and **kwargs and I cannot see my arguments defined in the function

Comment: At least your decorated functions do appear, do they ?-)

Comment: No they don't appear